# Why am i getting Uninitialized constant error if class in subfolder in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm having an odd issue that's haunting me. I have some custom classes defined in `/lib/**/**` that I'm trying to load in a controller. So given:

```
# dir: lib/forms/enums/data_type.rb
module Forms
  class DataType
    TEXT       = 0
    NUMBER     = 1
  end
end


# dir: controllers/form_controller.rb
class FormController < ApplicationController
  def update
   # Here, I get the uninitialized constant error for MyModule::DataType
   if params[:someAttr] ===  Forms::DataType::TEXT
    ...
   end
  ...
  end
...
end
```

However, if I place the `DataType` class in dir: `lib/forms/`, i.e. in the same folder as `forms`, instead of the subfolder `enums` , it can reference it just fine.

I'm sure I'm doing something basic very wrong, but I don't understand why Rails can find any classes under modules, but not in subdirectories?

Update/Edit: It seems to work if I refer to it add it under an additional submodule, and refer to it as `Forms::Enums::DataType::TEXT`, like so:

```
# dir: lib/forms/enums/data_type.rb
module Forms
  module Enums
    class DataType
      TEXT       = 0
      NUMBER     = 1
    end
  end
end
```

So, if I introduce a subdirectory,  is it required to always introduce a sub-module?

Comment: `So, if I introduce a subdirectory, is it required to always introduce a sub-module?` - yes

Comment: Take a look at [Rail 5 style (classic) autoloading](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants_classic_mode.html#autoloading-availability)

Comment: Note that you can always manually load a class if you need to. You don't _have_ to use rails autoloading, but it does help, and most rails devs expect it to be used. Also, if you don't use autoloading, you don't get auto reloading either.

Comment: Thank you for the help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like - As the comments to the question itself have pointed out,

1. If I introduce a subdirectory, if you need it autoloaded, it seems that a sub-module is required.
2. You can bypass this if you manually load a class